# I can't migrate the contract using truffle init

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am working to build a Dapp using Ganache, Web3, and Truffle frameworks. I am unable to compile the contracts using truffle compile. I am facing an error. I want to explain you in detail what I did.

Firstly I have created a directory by using

```
mkdir Election
```

Then I changed the directory to Election using

```
cd Election
```

Then I have used this truffle boxes to make the Dapp work simple

```
"truffle unbox pet-shop"
```

[image]

Then I have written a contract in the contracts directory Elections.sol
[image]

Then I went to the migrations directory and created a file for migrating  this contract using truffle migrate. Here I am facing the issue. I am getting a while compiling. I am attaching you both the Error and the file that I have created in the migrations directory. It will be good if you could please help me asap.

This is the migrations file that will be present in the migrations directory.
[image]

This is the Error file that I am getting when I am running

```
truffle migrate
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made little changes and it's working for me.

- name your file as your contract name. i.e Election.sol
- change function name since it shadowing the contract name.

(Truffle v5.0.9 (core: 5.0.9)
Node v10.15.2 )

Answer (score 0):

Try one thing, Change your constructor to `constructor(){}` instead of `function Election() public{}` because there has been some changes in Solidity's new versions.